# Animate resizing of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In my app, I'm trying to build an animation that resizes the `UIViewController` when a notification comes in.

I created a container `UIViewController` that encapsulates the child. I then wrote the code below to resize the child `UIViewController`.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5
                               delay:0
                             options:0
                          animations:^{
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                                  for(int i = 0; i < [self.viewControllers count]; i++) {
                                      UIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
                                      vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, [self topOffset], self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-[self topOffset]);
                                  }
                              }];
                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                          }];
```

However, what happens now is that the height change is performed immediately and the y change is animated, making it look like the view is sliding down. Any ideas as to what I could change to make it just resize?

Comment: Instead of animating the `frame`, try animating the `bounds` and `center` together and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Before animation all VC must have a frame

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [self.viewControllers count]; i++) {
   UIViewController *vc =   [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
   vc.view.frame =  self.view.frame;

 }
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5
                               delay:0
                             options:0
                          animations:^{
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                                  for(int i = 0; i < [self.viewControllers count]; i++) {
                                      UIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
                                      vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, [self topOffset], self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-[self topOffset]);
                                  }
                              }];
                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                          }];
```

Also height must be calculated like this

```
 self.view.frame.size.height - 2 * [self topOffset]
```

if you want same distance from bottom as up